# OnItemClick fails to load another activity

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

I've followed this tutorial http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/ and using the absolute code from that website i've made an apk and executed it on my AVD. The app work's well in displaying the list of apps installed on the device. But, when i click on a particular item from the list view, instead of loading the ApkListActivity which displays the app info, nothings happening. There are no errors displayed in my logcat as a result i have no idea where the problem might be.

I've even registered the AppData class in the application tags of the manifest file. But, the result is same.

Comment: You won't get much helpful info unless you post your relevant code. Also, what you're actually asking is "how can I debug this?" which is a valid question. Usually it comes down to making a breakpoint in all the places where you think the code is getting executed and seeing if that's happening. If you haven't used a debugger before, you can also add a bunch of log statements like System.out.println("this line got executed") etc..

Comment: @arnorhs The app is working after i've changed the class files into different packages according to the tutorial. Previously i've placed all the class files in one package. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.